# Invocation API for .NET

Tags: .net

The [Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) for the JVM allows custom instantiation of a JVM in a custom C++ application (i.e. it hosts a JVM in-process alongside the existing application). Is there a similar API for .NET? (I'm not talking about loading additional `AppDomain`s, but of completely bootstrapping a .NET instance within a given process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want the so called [Unmanaged CLR Hosting API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850(v=vs.100).aspx).